# unable to write macros with nested if in PCH file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macros, precompiled-headers, pch

I'm trying to write this piece of code in the `pch` file :
`#define someString

 if(x == 5) {

  if(y == 7) {

   someString = @"Test1"

   }

   else {

    someString = @"Test2"

   }

 }

else {

someString = @"TEST3"

}`

but to no avail ..
anybody can help ?

p.s. i don’t want to write it with this notation: (x == 5) ? @“test1” : @“test3”

Answer (score 2):

You can use the #if, #elif, and #else directives for this. Please see following sample code.

```
#define XVALUE 5
#define YVALUE 7

#if defined(XVALUE) && XVALUE == 5
    #if defined(YVALUE) && YVALUE == 7
        #define someString @"Test1"
    #else
        #define someString @"Test2"
    #endif
#else
    #define someString @"Test3"
#endif
```

You might want to make function which can replace some inline code resulting in a string value, as following:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
static inline NSString* SomeStringInline(int xValue, int yValue)
{
    if(xValue == 5)
    {
        if (yValue == 7) {
            return @"Test1";
        }
        else
        {
            return @"Test2";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return @"Test3";
    }
}
#endif
```

And you invoke this method from like

```
 NSLog(@"%@", SomeStringInline(5, 7));
```

And output will be "Test1".

Use whatever suites you.

For more help on macros:

- [Conditional Compilation (#if, #ifdef, #ifndef, #else, #elif, #endif, and defined)](http://www.tru64unix.compaq.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V40F_HTML/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_078.HTM)
- [#if, #elif, #else, and #endif Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: in the first code block, can i add multiple lines under #if defined(YVALUE) && YVALUE == 7 ?

Comment: Between the #if and #else or #endif block, you can add as many lines as you want. But, what do you want to add!